# eclipse new gradle project hold on task init

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am using gradle 5.2, eclipse 2018-12, buildship 3.0.

I specify the gradle local installation in eclipse config.

However when I try to create a new gradle project, it always hold on task:init,
there is no gradle project is created.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Like above screenshot shows, it always say " task:init ", what is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I update the buildship from 3.0.0 to 3.0.1, now I can create success!

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to try on creating this project from a command line, just to see if there is some output generated on console. I don't know what project you need specifically, but try for example:

```
gradle init --type java-application
```

Then we could see it problem occurs. If not, then it's an issue with your Eclipse setup.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. It helps. I did as you said and found that it is the issue of my eclipse.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue.

I happened to also have the Gradle console open in Eclipse and I can see that there is a prompt for Groovy/Kotlin being presented.

Eclipse: 18.12, Gradle: 5.4.1, Buildship: 3.0.0.v20181106-1441-m

[image: New Gradle Project]

Using Eclipse to update from the "Latest Eclipse Release" software site to Eclipse 19.3 with Buildship 3.1 and it worked perfectly.

[image]